# can you change the html notifications language?

Tags: html, forms, dom

so i have a simple form:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="" style="padding:7px">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cccel">Cel</label><br />
      <input class="form-control" id="ccel" name="cel" minlength="10" maxlength="10" type="text" type="number"  required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccelconf">Confirma tu Celular</label><br />
      <input class="form-control" id="ccelconf" name="cel" minlength="10"  maxlength="10"  type="text" name="celconf" type="number"  required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cocr">OCR</label><br />
      <input class="form-control" id="cocr" minlength="9"  maxlength="13"  type="text" name="ocr" type="number"  required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cocrconf">Confirma tu OCR </label><br />
      <input class="form-control" id="cocrconf" minlength="9"  maxlength="13"  name="ocrconf" type="number" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and my question is, can you change the required, min length notification language? 
or at least can you edit them?

how it would be if its possible.

Answer (score -1):

ok, it was editing the jquery.validate.js script, sorry.

ok, go to the file, and on the messages part just change how you want it:

```
messages: {
        required: "Este Campo es requerido",
        remote: "Please fix this field.",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
        url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
        date: "Please enter a valid date.",
        dateISO: "Please enter a valid date ( ISO ).",
        number: "Please enter a valid number.",
        digits: "Please enter only digits.",
        creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
        equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
        maxlength: $.validator.format( "Por favor no ingreses mas de {0} caracteres" ),
        minlength: $.validator.format( "Por favor ingresa al menos {0} caracteres" ),
        rangelength: $.validator.format( "Por favor ingresa un valor de entre {0} y {1} caracteres" ),
        range: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value between {0} and {1}." ),
        max: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}." ),
        min: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}." )
    },
```

Comment: Not an answer. If you posted the question by mistake, please delete it. If you have a clarification to make (so that it might become a well-defined answerable question), please edit the question. Do not post an answer unless you have answer.